# Delete node in binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have implemented the following methods for deleting a node in a BST for following the example that is posted [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/):

**class NodeT**

```
public class NodeT {
    int elem;
    NodeT left;
    NodeT right;
    public NodeT(int elem){
        this.elem=elem;
    }
}
```

**class BinaryTree**

```
public class BinaryTree {
    NodoT root;
    public void insertElem(int n){
        root=addRec(root,n);
    }
    public NodoT addRec(NodeT n, int elem){
        if (n==null){
            n=new NodeT(elem);
        }
        else{
            if (elem<n.elem){
                n.left=addRec(n.left,elem);
            }
            else{
                n.right=addRec(n.right,elem);
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
    public void inorder(NodeT n){
        if (n!=null){
            inorder(n.left);
            System.out.println(n.elem);
            inorden(n.right);
        }
    }

    public NodeT search(NodeT root, int n){
        if (root.elem==n) return root;
        else{
            if (n<root.elem){
                if (root.left!=null){
                    return search(root.left,n);
                }
                else return null;
            }
            else{
                if (root.right!=null){
                    return search(root.right,n);
                }
                else return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void delete(int n){
       root=deleteNode(root,n);
    }


    public NodeT deleteNode(NodeT curr, int n){
        NodoT answ;
        answ=search(curr,n);
        if (answ==null){
            System.out.println("not found");
            return curr;
        }
        else{

            if (curr.left==null)return curr.right; 
            else if (curr.right==null) return curr.left;
            curr.elem=minValue(curr.right);
            curr.right=deleteNode(curr.right,curr.elem);
        }
        return curr;
    }


    int minValue(NodoT curr){

        int min=curr.elem;
        while (curr.left!=null){
            menor=curr.left.elem;
            curr=curr.left;
        }
        return min;
    }


//main program


BinaryTree bt=new BinaryTree();        
   int data[]={50,30,70,20,40,60,80};

    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        bt.insertElem(data[i]);
    }
    bt.inorder(bt.root);

    bt.delete(20);
    bt.inorder(bt.root);


    bt.delete(30);
    bt.inorder(bt.root);


    bt.delete(50);
    bt.inorder(bt.root);
```

However, when I tested,  it prints "not found" on line `bt.delete(50);`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it happening for the first removal already, or only in subsequent removals?

Comment: what are `izq` and `der` in `addRec` function? I didn't see these properties in `NodeT`

Comment: @TranHo I have corrected the code

Comment: @LajosArpad in all the removals

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of mistakes in the code, I think your converted from you language and missed some variable names. However, I corrected the names and tested the code.

**Problem:** In your `deleteNode()`, you are not recurring down the tree i.e. checking If element is less than or greater than the value of `curr`. You need to add few more `IF` checks.

**Solution:** Replace your `deleteNode()` with this one.

```
public NodeT deleteNode(NodeT curr, int n){
    NodeT answ;
    answ=search(curr,n);
    if (answ==null){
        System.out.println("not found");
        return curr;
    }
    // need to check whether value is small or greater 
    if (n < curr.elem) 
        curr.left = deleteNode(curr.left, n); 
    else if (n > curr.elem) 
        curr.right = deleteNode(curr.right, n); 


    // if value is same, means this is the node to be deleted
    else{

        if (curr.left==null)
            return curr.right; 
        else if (curr.right==null) 
            return curr.left;
        curr.elem=minValue(curr.right);
        curr.right=deleteNode(curr.right,curr.elem);
    }
    return curr;
}
```

Comment: is there no way to use the search method that I have programmed?

Comment: I am using search method, you can see on line#3 in the code that i provided.

Comment: @Little, users must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then kindly mark 
that as answer. so that if someone have the same issue in future they can get a handy help without asking a new question. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

## insertElem

```
public void insertElem(int n){
    root=addRec(root,n);
}
```

You are overriding `root` each time you add some values, so at the second insert you forget about its parent and so on and you will end up only knowing about 80, since that's the last element that you insert and the last value that you override `root` with. `root` should only initialized if it's `null`, like

```
if (root == null) root=addRec(root,n);
```

## addRec

```
public NodoT addRec(NodeT n, int elem){
    if (n==null){
        n=new NodeT(elem);
    }
    else{
        if (elem<n.elem){
            n.left=addRec(n.left,elem);
        }
        else{
            n.right=addRec(n.right,elem);
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

You always set `n.left` or `n.right` to the value returned by `addRec`, which ruins your structure. You are correct to call `addRec`, but should only assign it to `n.left` or `n.right` if the respective value is `null`.

## inorder

Seems not to be relevant from our current point of view.

## search

Looks good.

## delete

Looks good.

## deleteNode

```
public NodeT deleteNode(NodeT curr, int n){
    NodoT answ;
    answ=search(curr,n);
    if (answ==null){
        System.out.println("not found");
        return curr;
    }
    else{

        if (curr.left==null)return curr.right; 
        else if (curr.right==null) return curr.left;
        curr.elem=minValue(curr.right);
        curr.right=deleteNode(curr.right,curr.elem);
    }
    return curr;
}
```

You are not comparing the actual numbers. The idea should be that the item to be removed will be searched in the right branch if the value is higher than the current node's value and the left branch otherwise. If the branch where you need to search at reaches `null`, then the item does not exist in the tree. See Zain Arshad's implementation. I would have done something similar, but since he has already implemented it, I refer to that and upvote it,